# ¿Cómo buscar en un archivo usando expresiones regulares?

Tags: python, regex

Estoy viendo la parte de expresiones regulares. Intento que este pequeño programa lea un archivo. Primeramente solicita que el nombre de un usuario y devolviendo el resto de texto que contiene el archivo sobre ese usuario. Si no hay coincidencia aparece un mensaje indicándolo.
Estoy atascado y no encuentro la forma de que salga el resto de datos.

---

**texto.txt**
Nombre: Antonio
Apellido: Perez
Edad:30
Nombre: Paco
Apellido: Peláez
Edad:39
Nombre: Julia
Apellido: Paz
Edad: 41

---

```
 import re
      txt = ".../Python/ProjectPython/texto.txt"
      x = input("Introduzca los tres primeros caracteres del nombre buscado:\n ")
 with open(txt, "r") as f:
     for datos in f:
         if re.findall(x, datos, re.IGNORECASE):
              print("Los resultados obtenidos son los siguientes:\n", datos)

         else:
              print("No se ha encontrado coincidencia :(")
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el contenido del archivo? No queda claro si tienes una línea o varias por persona. Edita tu pregunta.

Comment: el texto tiene esas líneas vacías?

Comment: Perdón, ya lo he editado

Answer (score 0):

**El código que compartes tiene un error de identación**

El *ciclo-for* accede a cada linea por separado sin guardar el texto completo ni ir agregando (*append*) las lineas, así que si posteriormente quieres mostrar el documento completo ya habrás perdido el acceso a esa información.

---

#### 1. Almacenar el archivo text.txt completo en la variable datos

Podrías primero guardar el documento completo en una variable
`datos`, luego con un *ciclo-for* recorrer cada línea respetando la
idea con la que has comenzado.

```py
# Almacenar el archivo text.txt completo en la variable datos
with open(txt, "r") as f:
    result=''
    datos=f.read()
```

#### 2. Iterar en cada línea del documento, salir(break) si se encontró resultado

```py
# Iterar en cada línea del documento, salir(break) si se encontró resultado
for line in datos.split('\n'):
    if re.findall(x, line, re.IGNORECASE):
        result=datos
        break
```

#### 3. Mostrar resultado si existe

````
Al final muestras el resultado si existe con un *if-Statement*

``` python
if result:
    print("Los resultados obtenidos son los siguientes:\n", datos)
else:
    print("No se ha encontrado coincidencia: ",x)
````

### # Resultado

Como resultado el código entero sería:

```py
import re

txt = ".../Python/ProjectPython/texto.txt"
x = input("Introduzca los tres primeros caracteres del nombre buscado:\n ")

with open(txt, "r") as f:
    result=''
    datos=f.read()

for line in datos.split('\n'):
    if re.findall(x, line, re.IGNORECASE):
        result=datos
        break

if result:
    print("Los resultados obtenidos son los siguientes:\n", datos)
else:
    print("No se ha encontrado coincidencia: ",x)
```

Entrada (éxito):

```
Introduzca los tres primeros caracteres del nombre buscado:
 Ant
```

Salida (éxito):

```
Los resultados obtenidos son los siguientes:
 Nombre: Antonio
Apellido: Perez
Edad:30
Nombre: Paco
Apellido: PelÃ¡ez
Edad:39
Nombre: Julia
Apellido: Paz
Edad: 41
```

Entrada (error):

```
Introduzca los tres primeros caracteres del nombre buscado:
 Alf
```

Salida (error):

```
No se ha encontrado coincidencia:  Alf
```

---

#### Bonus

En linux (en windows puedes agregar grep) es posible buscar en la consula un *patrón* con regex en varios archivos en varias carpetas, tienes que usar el siguiente comando:

```sh
grep -rl [patrón] *
```

Como explican [[acá](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55325/how-to-use-grep-command-to-find-text-including-subdirectories)] `-r` garantiza la búsqueda en sub directorios y `-l` garantiza solo escribir el título omitiendo el contenido (omitir si se quiere obtener el documento completo).

En python se puede emplear este comando usando el módulo *os*: